# Error in mapmyindia API

Tags: android, api, autocomplete, mapmyindia-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHRQg.png)I am developing an application in which user search for places using Auto-suggest API of mapmyindia. But in the activity, I am not able to import License Manager. I have followed every step for setting up project guided by mapmyindia website.

demoapplication

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.mmi.LicenceManager;

public class DemoApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LicenceManager.getInstance().setRestAPIKey("");
    LicenceManager.getInstance().setMapSDKKey("");
}
}
```

Comment: Can you check if you have included jar/aar file into your project.

Comment: yes, compile files('libs/map_sdk_2.1.jar')

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, can you check if you are able to run demo application? .

Comment: Actually, it got some of it's own errors, getResources() and getActivity() are highlighted in red in the activities.

Comment: did you tried syncing the gradle?

Comment: yes, i did sync it.

Comment: try to create new project and run it without adding mapmyindia jar. This Issue is not related to library.

Comment: Ok, i did it without adding jar and it is showing the same thing in demo application, you can see the image from the link i have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i figured it out, i did not added map jar file into libs folder that is why some of its feature were not working, i pasted the file from libs folder from mapmyindia SDK android project.

Comment: can u share the jar file ?  I am getting zip file when i download from here [https://www.mapmyindia.com/api/advanced-maps/sdk/android]